# i need a brief and simple understable advice to understand this code process

Tags: c

I am now learning the pointer and memory section of C. Now I am stuck on this code. I am not understanding how this code process and how the code shows result `contestants[2] = 2`. Please consider me as a very new learner and answer briefly how a single code worked and how's the result 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int contestants[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *choice = contestants;

    contestants[0] = 2;
    contestants[1] = contestants[2];
    contestants[2] = *choice;
    printf("I'm going to pick contestant number %i\n", contestants[2]); return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int contestants[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

`contestants` is an array of integrs, indexed starting at `0`, with values `contestants[0] == 1`, `contestants[1] == 2` and `` `contestants[2] = 3 ``.

```
int *choice = contestants;
```

`choice` is an integer pointer, assigned here to the address of the `contestants` array, which is the address of the first element of the `contestants` array. Therefore, `*choice` will give you the same result as `contestants[0]`.

```
contestants[0] = 2;
```

This assigns `2` to `contestants[0]`. Now `contestants[0] == 2` and, therefore, `*choice == 2`. The `contestants` array now looks like `{2, 2, 3}`.

```
contestants[1] = contestants[2];
```

Assigns the value `2` to `contestants[1]`. Now the `contestants` array looks like `{2, 3, 3}`.

```
contestants[2] = *choice;
```

Assigns `*choice` which is still the same as `contestants[0]` to `contestants[2]`. So the `contestants` array looks like `{2, 3, 2}`.

```
printf("I'm going to pick contestant number %i\n", contestants[2]); return 0;
```

Prints `contestants[2]`, which is `2` as you observed.

Comment: @Sahriarrahmansupto Yes. `choice` is a pointer to an integer and it points to the same memory location as `contestants[0]` which holds the value `2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `contestants` is an array of type integers which contains values `{1, 2, 3}`.
2. `choice` is a pointer of type `int` pointing to valid memory location of `contestants`.
3. Each element in array `contestants` are accessed as `contestants[i]`, where `i` is index of array starting from `0`. `contestants[0] = 2;` is what assigning value `2` to index location `0`.
4. `contestants[2] = *choice;` - choice is a pointer, `*choice` is called dereferencing pointer to get the value pointing by pointer `choice` which is `2`.

Typical memory layout is as follows,

```
              contestants[] 
choice           0      1     2 
+-----+       +-------------------+
|0x100|------>|  1   |  2   |  3  |              
|     |       |      |      |     |
+-----+       +-------------------+
            0x100  0x104  0x108
```